# simple way to code function which does different steps with different given inputs

Tags: function, python-3.x

I want to know if there is a simple way to code function that does different things when different data are given.
For example, the function below will give the value of remaining unknown for f=ma

```
def f_m_a(f,m,a):  
    if f is None:   
        return m*a  
    if m is None:  
        return f/a  
    if a is None:  
        return f/m
```

Making separate cases like the above for a long equation will take time and complicate the code.
Is there a way to code more efficiently without writing the separate cases?

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is no way to do simplification.

The only "optimization" can be done here is

```
def f_m_a(f,m,a):  
    if f is None:   
        return m*a  
    return f/(m or a)
```

But readability is very bad. And here is the problem with zero-values for 'm'...